# Decomposition of a vector space in term of $\text{Im}(f)$ with $f^3=f$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following exercise in linear algebra.

Let $f:V\to V$ be a linear map so that $f^3=f$. Prove that $$V=\text{Im}(f)\oplus\text{Im}(f+id)\oplus\text{Im}(f-id).$$

I can show the above equality with $\text{Im}$ replaced by $\text{Ker}$, without using the assumption $f^3=f$. However I do not know how to continue.

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is equivalent to the assertion that any $x \in V$ can be written as $f(a)+f(b)+b+f(c)-c$ for some $a,b,c \in V$. Letting $a=0$, $b=\frac12x$, and $c=-\frac12x$ solves this problem trivially. Am I wrong?

Comment: @KennyLau You still need to show the intersection of the images is trivial.

Comment: @KennyLau Maybe the rought thing is to show that the representation is unique.

Comment: I don't think this is a direct sum. Let $f$ be the identity. Then clearly $f^3 = f$ and $\operatorname{Im}(f) = \operatorname{Im}(f + id)$.

Comment: @Doughnut Pump You are right! In any case, I wonder what is the correct statement in this case. Note that if $f^2=f$, we have $V=\text{Im}(f)\oplus \text{Im}(f-id)$...